# Get links related to a given keyword (python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

```
import requests, urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

keyword = 'hello'

r = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q={keyword}')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
links = []
for item in soup.find_all('h3', attrs={'class' : 'r'}):
    links.append(item.a['href'])
print(links)
```

I got this code but it isn't working. Any help? There aren't any errors but it seems it can't find any link related to the given keyword.
Output:

```
[]
```

Comment: From what I can tell the `<h3>` is inside the `<a>`, but you are trying to parse it as if it's the other way around.

Comment: Also first you need to accept the ToS. Or else only the Terms of Use will be visible. You might want to use selenium for that